# Missing Username on users signed-up with custom identity providers

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identityserver3

In recent months, we've managed to integrate our existing Identity Server 3 with AAD B2C. It's of course registered as a Custom Identity Provider by following [this instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp). And everything works fine when it comes to authentication itself. All users from our existing database (which is behind our Identity Server 3) are able to sign-in with AAD B2C without any problem. And as you can guess all of them, once they sign-in for a first time, become Azure Active Directory (B2C Tenant) users as well. 
But, we've just recently also noticed that none of them has correct User Name and Source values in the list of users in our AAD B2C Tenant (see picture). 
Does anybody have any idea what we might be missing on either Identity Server or Azure AD B2C side (or both) and what could be a possible reason for not-populating these values?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a **User** object for an external identity (e.g. an IdentityServer-managed identity) is created in the Azure AD B2C directory, it is created as follows:

```
{
    "accountEnabled": false,
    "creationType": null,
    ...
    "userIdentities": [
        {
            "issuer": "...",
            "issuerUserId": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

where the **UserIdentity** object is set as follows:

- The **issuer** property is set to the string representation of the external identity provider that issued the user identifier, such as `https://myidentityserver3.azurewebsites.net/identity`.
- The **issuerUserId** property is set to the Base64 representation of the user identifier that is issued by the external identity provider.

When the **All Users** menu is opened in the Azure AD B2C portal, then these external users are listed with the **issuer** value in the **User Name** column and "Unknown" in the **Source** column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I see the point but still don't get it if I could control these values somehow? Should these values be issued as claims on Identity Server side? For us it'll be very suitable if we could have usernames that make some more sense so we can relate them to the users in source database.

Comment: You don't have to control them. They are issued in the ID token from IdentityServer. Other than the user identifier, what identifies a given user in the source database, which can also be issued in the ID token from IdentityServer?

Comment: OK, I get it. Email for example. Or username, even better.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure how this answers my question how to solve this issue? How should I set above-mentioned attributes to avoid having "Unknown" in Source column? You just said how the model behind looks like but I'm wondering how can I set those fields so I have appropriate values. Do you have example for that?

Comment: Apologies, @markodj, the key point is that, for an external user, you can't set any special values. i.e. You can't control what is displayed in the **All Users** list.

Comment: Oh man, that's so bad, it'd be great if we could control it during a sign-up process with an external IdP. But anyways, thanks for clarification.